# RegEx how to match "act. 10" but not "act. 10/2"?

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I want to match only strings like "act. 1" or "act. 200" but no strings with a sub-numbre (e.g. "act. 30/1" or "act. 400/1").

My pattern `act\.(.)\d+(?!\/)` matchs "act. 1", "act. 200", but also "act. 3" and "act. 40". How can I exclude all strings with a slash in the digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of capturing any char in group 1 `(.)`, you could match 1 or more whitespace chars using `\s+`. Then after the digits, add a word boundary followed by the negative lookahead.

```
act\.\s+\d+\b(?!/)
```

**Explanation**

- `act\.\s+` Match `act.` followed by 1+ whitespace chars
- `\d+\b` Match 1+ digit followed by a word boundary
- `(?!/)` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not `/`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LuJY9J/1)

Comment: Thx, works great! I you (.) instead of \s+ because I want match normal and non-breaking-spaces.
Update: just found out: [\u00a0| ] is a alternative for my case